# font-size varying on container width in iOS

Tags: html, css

We have a number of divs on a page containing text. The text is explicitly set to a certain font-size via CSS. In some circumstances the font-size is increasing without our intervention. It seems to be related to the length of the text in the DIVs. i.e. once it gets to a particular size adding a character increases the font-size, removing it again reduces the font-size.

We haven't got any fancy libraries included to scale the font.

In chrome dev tools it shows the variation in the font set via CSS, and then the computed size here:

[image]

Why does the font go from 16px to 19.555555px? What are we missing?

thanks!

Comment: Is this on a live website that we can take a look at? Or can you post the relevant sections of your html and css?

Comment: Add css
html { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; }

Comment: Are the font-sizes in your CSS-file purely specified in Pixels or are you also using EM?

Comment: It's not on a live website currently. We are specifying the heights using px not EM. We've tried html { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; } and it appears to make no perceivable difference.